# I'm getting KeyError: 'bbox' in my code and I don't see why

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This code is related to my research work. I am using the Yolo model for which I am creating bounding boxes. Now I am using this code for creating bounding boxes.

```
bboxs= np.stack(df['bbox'].apply(lambda x: np.formstring(x[1:-1], sep=',')))
    for i, column in enumerate(['xmin','ymin','w','h'])
    df[column]=bboxs[:,i]
    df['x_center']=df['xmin'] + df['w']/2
    df['x_center']=df['ymin'] + df['h']/2
    df['classes']=0
    df['w'] /=1024
    df['h'] /=1024
    df['x_center'] /=1024
    df['y_center'] /=1024
    df= df[['image_id','classes','x_center','y_center','w','h']]
    df.head()
```

when I run this code got kind of error shows

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
                                4 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi inpandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()7
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()


KeyError: 'bbox'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)


   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'bbox'
```

I am a beginner in python, so am unable to figure out what the issue is. I tried looking for solutions to similar questions but could not resolve the issue.

Comment: I am not sure, but are you sure `bbox` key exists in `df` dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

KeyError: 'bbox' when accessing the column of a dataframe (df) indicates that there is no column with the name 'bbox' in df.
To check which columns exist, they could be output as follows: `print(df.columns)`.